# File Upload in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to upload file in folder. I am not able to find the mistake. The UploadFile View returns on same view after uploading file.

Model Class:

```
public class Upload
    {
        public int UploadId { get; set; }
        public string UploadTitle { get; set; }
        public string UploadURL { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the Controller(FileUpload) Action:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, Upload upload)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string fil = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Files"), fil);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    upload.UploadURL = "/Content/Uploads/Files/" + file.FileName;
                }
                db.Uploads.Add(upload);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(upload);
        }
```

In my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile, "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/Form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">
                <label for="file">Upload Image  for Slide:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width:50%" />
            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Did you try debugging the code? Does the `Model.IsValid` call return true? It's impossible to guess without some information

Comment: Do you have the "[HttpPost]" attribute before the function in Controller?

Comment: @Eru  "[HttpPost]" attribute on the code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't get any error.

Comment: Is your post action being hit ?

Comment: I have used you code and it works fine as far as uploading the file. You have to make sure that you have you folders created '/Content/Uploads/Files/' otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: If you post a link to your github repo we can more quickly identify your issue

Answer (score 4):

Hi I have tried your same code its works for me.

**Controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string fil = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Files"), fil);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View("UploadFile");
        }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/Form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">
            <label for="file">Upload Image  for Slide:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width:50%" />
        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I have found small mistake in you code in Html.BeginForm in action name `"` (double quotes is missing)

Comment: it seems that you didn't use the model.

Comment: If you want to use the model you can use it and pass through the UploadFile action

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to mention the required field on UploadURL in above model class:

```
public class Upload
    {
        public int UploadId { get; set; }
        public string UploadTitle { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UploadURL { get; set; }

    }
```

Required Field validation on UploadURL field restricted the file upload here. I removed the Required field validation from the field.

Comment: Is this the answer or just additional info. just edit your post.