# Photo is getting damaged on Upload C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an upload in my project and when I upload the photo it does not show. If I try to open it from the folder on my PC, it says that the file type isn't supported. It's a `.png` file.

**Here is my controller code:**

```
 string fileName = Path.GetFileName(expenseReportsDetails.ImageUpload.FileName);
                    var date = DateTime.Today;
                        var newdate = date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                        var lookup = db.CompanyNames.Where(a => a.CompanyId == com.CompanyId).FirstOrDefault();
                        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Expenses/" + lookup.AccountNumber + "/" + newdate + "/");
                        expenseReportsDetails.Receipt = fileName;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        Boolean dirExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
                        if (!dirExist)
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        }

                        string file = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Expenses/" + lookup.AccountNumber + "/" + newdate + "/" + fileName);
                        FilePath = file;

                        Boolean isexist = System.IO.File.Exists(file);

                        if (isexist)
                        {
                            var d = new FileInfo(file);

                            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                        }
                        System.IO.File.Create(file);
```

It creates the folders and puts the image in the directory but the image is not viewable.

Here is how I get the file:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Receipt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
<input type="file" name="ImageUpload" onchange="ShowPreview(this)" id="ImageUpload" />
<img src="~/Documents/Expenses/@Model.Receipt" alt="preview" style="width:100px;background-color:#d3d3d3;" id="imgbrowers" />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Receipt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"~/Documents/Expenses/" + lookup.AccountNumber + "/" + newdate + "/" +fileName` is not same as `"~/Documents/Expenses/@Model.Receipt"`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya So it is getting damaged because of this? This only to select the file not to actually view it. It does show up in the view as I have selected it. That is what that is for, at least I thought. The view page is this:    <img src="~/Documents/Expenses/@Model.AccountNumber/@newdate/@item.Receipt" />

Comment: What do you mean by damaged? You need to check the file path where the file is uploaded and the image url assigned to the src of img tag. Are they same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have posted, it looks like you have missed a piece of code that writes the content of the uploaded file into the file created at the server end.

Your code `System.IO.File.Create(file);` returns you back a FileStream that you can use to write the content into the file. The content from the uploaded file can be access in your controller by reading the InputStream from the HttpPostedFileBase instance. Something like below

```
var uploadedFileStream=expenseReportsDetails.ImageUpload.FileStream;
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
     uploadedFileStream.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Please note: I haven't checked the working of the above piece of code, just giving you a direction to look at.
You can also look at other answers like the one in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457784/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-5) if you can a different approach to writing the uploaded file to the server

Comment: I looked to your link and added :  expenseReportsDetails.ImageUpload.SaveAs(file); in place of System.IO.File.Create(file); and that seem to do the trick Thanks for your help!